# Java OutputStreamWriter UTF-16 CVS wrong character on StartLine

Tags: java, excel, csv, io

i need to write a simple `CSV file` using `OutputStreamWriter` everything works `OK` but i have a problem a have in the first `Header` on the CSV the outer left on every line  seems to `ADD` improperly a `Character or a sequence of them` in the `String` here is my `Java Code`

```
private final Character SEPARATOR=';'; 
private final Character LINE_FEED='\n';
public void createCSV(final String fileName)//......
{        
    try
    (final OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    final OutputStreamWriter writer=new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,StandardCharsets.UTF_16);)
    {            
         final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder().append("Fecha").append(SEPARATOR)
        .append("NºExp").append(SEPARATOR)                       
        .append("NºFactura").append(SEPARATOR).append(LINE_FEED);            
        writer.append(builder.toString());                         
        writer.append(builder.toString());                         
        writer.flush();           
    }catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}    
}
```

unfortunalety i am receiving this ouput always happens in the first line if i repeat the same output to the second line in the `CSV` everything works smoothly is a Java problem or is my Excel gives me nightmares??.. thank a lot..

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a superfluous byte order mark (BOM), `\uFFFE`, a zero width space, its byte encoding used to determine whether it is UTF-16LE (little endian) or UTF-16-BE (big endian).

Write `"UTF16-LE"`, which has the Windows/Intel ordering of least significant byte, most significant byte.

```
StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE
```